# UIWebView open url from file

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am making an app on iphone and I have got stucked at one point. I want to read a text file which has some list of URLs and then I need to read that file and open those URLs one by one in UIWebVIew. Can anyone suggest me how can I do that?? with some sample example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about using Plist file instead of text file?

Comment: I dont have used plist, can you tell me how can I go ahead and make use of it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `NSDataDetector`, you can find links by `dataDetectorWithTypes:error:` using `NSTextCheckingTypeLink`. More documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this option and will get back to you. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey Xan, My requirements got changed and I didnt tried the above solution. But thanks for you help.

Comment: Hi everyone, I need some help. I have made an app and at the end of the app I get csv file as a result. I want to upload that file to the server whose username and password is known to me. can any1 tell me what is the wat to do this. Can i do a SCP or FTP from the xcode application? PLease do help